# Database design: getting more readable rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm creating tables for a database (with Redshift) to store the events of multiple mobile apps which are recovered from multiple sources.
Problem with this is that it's not very user-friendly / explicit as it forces them to make queries into multiple tables to recover the values of the columns to understand what it's in the rows, as most of the data in the rows of the event table are integers.

```
CREATE TABLE source (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    value           string NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE application (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    value           string NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE platform (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    value           string NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE country (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    value           string NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE event (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    source_id       integer REFERENCES source(id),
    application_id  integer REFERENCES application(id),
    platform_id     integer REFERENCES platform(id),
    country_id      integer REFERENCES country(id),

    ...

    updated_at      date NOT NULL,
    value           decimal(100, 2) NOT NULL
);
```

For example, I thought of using the ENUM type to directly get the values but I feel like it's less flexible. Do you think there's an alternate solution I could use ?

Thanks!

Comment: How about creating a view where the tables are joined so that the values are directly visible in the view?

Comment: It is common to have a de-normalized layer which is used for reporting. Kimbal star modelling is one of the most common modelling patterns for this. This way the application can have a normalized structure and reporting is simplified.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Didn't think of views, but I think it's a very simple and effective solution there. I'm going to take a look at kimbal's star modelling as well. Thanks again!

Comment: You can use inheritance I think this is a good solution for your case

Answer (score -2):

Try to combine all  to one table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Values (
    kind            integer
    id              integer,
    value           string NOT NULL
);
```

set kind and id as primary key, you can find and access your unique data by kind and id, your kind will be type and id will be specific id, and both will be unique primary key

for example kind can be

```
source = 1, 
application = 2,
platform = 3,
country = 4
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea, do not do this unless you want massive scalability problems...